# Utilize IPSLib for IP.Board on External PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have wrote a PHP script that grabs the latest forum posts by categories that I want, which works fine and everything, however my problem lies in the actual output of the code itself, previously I was utilizing XenForo and could use their API on external pages no problem, now that we have migrated to IP.Board I am trying to utilize the IPSLib Library in order to use the parsing system so that the posts I have pulled don't show up all messy and with bbcode everywhere.

The code that pulls the information from IP.Board's database works fine, again I'm simply trying to load & use the IPSLib from IP.Board.

My question is how, if possible, can you load the IPSLib in order to utilize the functions provided by the library?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
require_once( 'forums/initdata.php' );
require_once( IPS_ROOT_PATH.'/sources/base/ipsRegistry.php' );
require_once( IPS_ROOT_PATH.'/sources/base/ipsController.php' );
$registry = ipsRegistry::instance();
$registry->init();

$classToLoad = IPSLib::loadLibrary( 'forums/admin/sources/classes/text/parser.php', 'classes_text_parser' );
$parser = new $classToLoad();
$parser->set( array( 'parseArea'      => 'topics',
                     'parseBBCode'    => true,
                     'parseHtml'      => false,
                     'parseEmoticons' => true ) );
```

and finally where the text you want to parse from BBcode -> HTML use:

```
print $parser->BBCodeToHtml( $toParse );
```